# Cisco ASA logging buffered spams terminal and console lines

Tags: cisco-asa, syslog

I have several routers, switches and firewalls that send logs to a syslog server without interfering with the console line.

I'm testing an ASA 5506 (running IOS 9.5.2) at a remote location that doesn't have a syslog server so I'm trying to use 'logging buffered' to troubleshoot a VPN issue and when I run the following

```
no logging console
logging buffered debug
debug crypto isa 127
```

debug messages start spamming the console line and I need to reboot the ASA to make any changes on it. (*terminal no monitor gives me a Monitor option not supported for the console*

I thought the 'logging buffered' command was only supposed to log to the internal buffer? Then I could go in an view them later. What's going on here?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Adding *logging console errors* or *logging console emergencies* did not help.

**EDIT:** *sh run | inc log* gives me this output

```
logging console emergencies
logging buffered debugging
logging asdm informational
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember running into a similar issue. One of my settings was turning the console logging back on. I never did determine what did it, but if my memory serves I got around it by only logging errors to the console using `logging console errors` to stop the debug messages.

Comment: Tim, I will try that when I get home. I just realized I have no way of remotely restarting the ASA if it starts spamming the console line again.

Comment: @WinskiTech I use a 'reload at' 5 minutes in the future as a saftey net if im risking lost remote access. It works well for this kind of thing.